# how to get express js data using json

Tags: json, node.js, express

how have i to change to get all my data when going to localhost:3000/todos and a specific data when going to localhost:3000/todos/1 or localhost:3000/todos/2 ?

My app.js is:

```
/*jslint node:true*/
'use strict';


var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function Todo() {
this.todos = [];
this.nextId = 1;
}

Todo.prototype.find = function (id) {
var todo = this.todos.filter(function (item) {
    return item.taskId === id;
})[0];
if (null === todo) {
    throw new Error('task not found');
}
return todo;
};

app.get('/todos/:id', function (request, response) {
var taskId = request.params.id;
try {
    response.json(Todo.find(taskId));
} catch (exeception) {
    response.sendStatus(404);
}
});
app.listen(3000);
```

and my todos.json is:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "premiere action"
},
{
"id" : 2,
"name": "deuxieme action"
}
]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can `require` a JSON file in Node, and get the data into a variable.

Comment: For example, `var todos = require('./todos.json');`. Todos will then store the JSON object from your `todos.json` file.